# How to return an enumerable object when using repository pattern?

Tags: c#, .net, repository-pattern

I am working on a simple WCF application and I am having trouble with properly setting up the Repository pattern. The communication pattern of the application is roughly as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4Xjv.png).

I am concerned with the part that says `Admin Console Mode`. In this mode, the admin has access to some admin features like adding users and viewing existing users etc.

Abstract contract of one of the entities, `Users`, needed for this mode, is as follows:

```
public interface IUserRepository
{
    byte AddUser(string _loginname, string _loginpass);
    Users ShowAllUsers();
}
```

The concrete implementation of this repository:

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    public UserRepository(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public byte AddUser(string _loginname, string _loginpass)
    {
        . . .
    }

    public Users ShowAllUsers()
    {
        string query = "select login_name,created_time from users";

        using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
            {                    
                conn.Open();

                using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if(!reader.Read())
                        return null;

                    return new Users
                    {
                        Login_Name = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("login_name")),
                        Login_Pass = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("login_pass")),
                        Created_Time = reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("created_time")),
                    };
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From the Host layer, How do I access the list of Users objects returned from the `ShowAllUsers` method? I tried this way:

```
public void ShowUsers()
{
    Users user = _repo.ShowAllUsers();

    Console.WriteLine("Name\tCreated Time");

    foreach(Users u in user)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}",u.Login_Name,u.Created_Time);
    }
}
```

From what I understand, this does not work obviously since the Users object is not an enumerable object. How do I modify the `Users` entity and the `repository contract` and the `repository implementation` so that the `Users` object is returned to be displayed on the screen?

[Users.cs](http://pastebin.mozilla.org/1571331)
[UserRepository.cs](http://pastebin.mozilla.org/1571334)
[IUserRepository.cs](http://pastebin.mozilla.org/1571335)

Comment: I have included definition `Users.cs` at the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entity:

```
// note the singular form, it makes much more sense for me, as far as the object represents a single entity (user)
// also not an interface, optionally
public class User : IUser
{
}
```

Repository:

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<IUser> ShowAllUsers()
    {
        ...
        while (reader.Read())
        {
             yield return new User
             {
                 ...
             };
        }
    }
}
```

I recommend yo use interfaces everywhere, because if you will want to switch from ADO.NET query to an ORM, you will need to rewrite much less code.

---

Usage:

```
foreach (User u in users)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} created on {1}", u.Login, u.CreationTime);
}
```

Comment: +1. You may want to mention that `if(!reader.Read()) return` becomes `while(reader.Read()) yield return`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Sure, you're right, added by myself in the same moment you suggested that :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Thanks! Will take care about that. Anyway it was wiped when raid died(

Comment: @abatishchev: Excuse my ignorance, but could you please let know what contract IUser interface should contain?

Comment: @KishorNanda: All the same properties what you expose by User. Such interface existence makes possible to return actually different classes from ADO.NET or ORM repositories (implementing IUserRepository) hidden by IUser. Also make `User` class private, and inject it with IoC container.

Comment: @abatishchev: Thank you for explanation. Can you also recommend me any reading list for gaining knowledge in these kinds of areas, (usage of interfaces, repository pattern)? As for IOC, it made my head hurt when trying to understand it, so I thought I would set it up once the application reaches to at least v0.1 :)

Comment: @KishorNanda: You know the topic is so wide so I fine it difficult to recommend any specific reading, I'm sorry.

Comment: @KishorNanda: Regarding IoC it's not complex as seems to be. In general it allows you to register an implementation of particular interface by specific class. Then you query the container by interface, it lookups internally and returns you a previously registered class hidden by the interface. So you can switch between the implementations without rewriting any lines of code!

Comment: @abatishchev: Thank you for the IOC explanation. I can understand about the topic being wide. I will try searching here and programmers.se.